# Visual C++ Remote Debugging causes blank property page

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm experiencing an odd and continously reproducable issue with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate I'm hoping someone can help me glean insight into.

I recently deployed a C++ application, I am developing, to one of my older laptops. When executed, nothing happens. Almost literally. It simply ends execution and returns immediately. It's supposed to do quite a bit more. I thought I'd address this problem using Visual Studios automatic deployment and debugging abilities.

I like to take things in very small increments when trying new things, and the [guides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) [I've found](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146838/Remote-debugging-with-Visual-Studio-2010) [on how](http://www.itworld.com/article/2699037/development/how-to-set-up-remote-debugging-in-visual-studio-2013.html) [to remotely debug and deploy](http://gpriaulx.co/2015/12/visual-studio-2015-remote-debugging/) have left me still feeling a bit confused/unsure.

So - I took the smallest step I could, by just selecting 'Remote Windows Debugger' and clicking that:

[image: Let's run the remote debugger, yay!]

This *expectedly* pops up an error message:

[image: Error box, not yay]

Following the advice, I am ***unexpectedly*** greeted with this in the property pages:

[image: Uhm... What?]

I have absolutely no idea why this happens.

I know the cause, in a sense. By fiddling around I found that the debugging changes are contained within the `Application.vcxproj.user` file. Prior to running/configuring any remote debugging it looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
</Project>
```

after just attempting to run remote debugging, it looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsRemoteDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Reverting to the previous file state, the properties show up just like they're supposed to.

But why (seemingly) any change causes Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate to go a bit sideways is beyond me. I first stumbled on the issue by following one of the aforementioned guides where I started out by just updating the `Deployment Directory` in the properties and then clicking `Apply`. This caused Vs2013 to crash and lead to the same blank property page.

I should note that this issue occurs with a freshly created console application.

Anyone ever tried anything similar or got any suggestions as to how to perhaps cure this problem?